# Eclipse can't find ROS binaries on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, ros

I am trying to setup a development environment for ros using the eclipse tutorial found on the ros website, http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs. I've followed the "Catkin-y" approach. I've made sure that eclipse is run out of a shell that has the ros paths set, including my catkin workspace.

The environment builds fine, but when I go to configure a run and click on browse project for binaries, none are found. the tutorial doesn't give any suggestions if this fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know if This problem is Solved or not

But You Can use catkin-tools (`catkin build` instead of `catkin_make`) that has a better CMake Structures (no top level `CMakeLists.txt` in `src` folder)